# Хранение изображений в ФС, разработка Веб-приложения, java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, tomcat, файловая-система

Делаю веб-приложение, в БД у продуктов храню название файла картинки Продукта, а сами картинки храню в файловой системе на диске `D://images/*.jpg`. После того как из БД все продукты прочитал, хочу отобразить их на странице. В JSP не могу отобразить эти картинки, не знаю где указать путь, который должен быть задан в конфиге моего приложения, покажите пожалуйста как это сделать и как отобразить картинки на JSP.

Работаю в среде разработки IDEA, язык программирования java. Возможно путь к картинкам нужно указать в `web.xml`, но в jsp `<img src="D://images/${product.img}">` не отображается.

Comment: вы должны хранить не на диске `D://images/*.jpg` а относительно папки webapp

Comment: @Виктор нет, строго снаружи веб-приложения и томката

Answer (score 1):

Например путь на диске к каталогу картинок можете указать в параметре контекста web-приложения.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <description>Где лежат мои картинки</description>
    <param-name>my.package.PATH_TO_MY_IMAGES</param-name>
    <param-value>d:/images</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Потом составляете сервлет, как написал @cache, но с небольшими изменениями

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = request.getPathInfo();
    String pathToMyImages = request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("my.package.PATH_TO_MY_IMAGES");
    File file = new File(pathToMyImages, filename);
    ...
```

Отступление от темы конфигурации пути
`request.getPathInfo()` вернёт, то что стоит за * в шаблоне /images/*, предваряя знаком / и исключая параметры запроса.
`http://foo/images/img001.png?param=123` -> `/img001.png`

Возвращение к теме
Кроме параметра контекста можно использовать `Application Environment Entries`. Кое-кто (разработчик javaee) считает что это предпочтительней параметров контекста.

web.xml

```
<env-entry>
    <description>Где лежат мои картинки</description>
    <env-entry-name>path_to_my_images</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>d:/images</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

Используем в программе.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = request.getPathInfo();
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    String pathToMyImages = (String) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/path_to_my_images");
    File file = new File(pathToMyImages, filename);
    ...
```

Или можете внедрить в поле сервлета. Если это сработает, то действительно предпочтительнее.

```
@WebServlet("/images/*")
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(lookup="path_to_my_images")
    private String pathToMyImages;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filename = request.getPathInfo();
        File file = new File(pathToMyImages, filename);
        ...
```

Чтобы не править web.xml, на сервере tomcat можно добавить в конфигурацию сервера ($CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml для tomcat 7) глобальную environment entry

```
<Server>
    ...
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        ...
        <Environment name="path_to_my_images" type="java.lang.String" value="d:/images"/>
        ...
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
</Server>
```

Внедрение ресурса в программу тоже, что и выше. В web.xml ничего дописывать не надо.
Таким не хитрым образом на каждом сервере можно иметь свою папку с картинками, не прибегая к правке web.xml

Ну и конечно ничто не мешает применить какую-нибудь библиотеку конфигурации, которая может работать в web-приложении. Такие имеются.

Картинки вставляются как-то так `<img src="${request.contextPath}/images/${product.img}"/>`

Comment: всё это хорошо, кроме одного НО...  как правило разработка идёт на одной машине, и в большей части под windows, а работает на сервере под линуксами. и каждый раз править ручками пути не есть приятная вшь.

Comment: @Вадим можно применить более сложную схему. Есть `resource-env-reference`. Тогда path_to_my_images будет ссылаться не  напрямую на строку с путём, а на некий ресурс (такая же строка с путём), который может быть определён в конфигурации сервера и меняться прямо на ходу. Но это зависит от сервера. Могу привести пример для wildfly на досуге. Что нужно для томката сами ищите. Начало у всех стандартное, продолжение разное.

Comment: у меня всё это решено для tomcat, работает превосходно, я просто сделал замечания для автора и для будущих искателей. решение несколько не тривиальное, требуется добавление jar в папку tomcat. и защита от постороннего вторжения с помощью   WebFilter.